# How do I check for a collision in a Snake game, without triggering on the head block

Tags: javascript

I am making a snake game. It is supposed to end when I go over a block I have already been to.
The issue is that it trips the collision check on every space so you lose from the start.
What do I need to do to solve this issue?

```
var SNAKE_DIM = 10;
var SNAKE_COLOR = Color.green;
var SNAKE_WIDTH=40;
var SNAKE_HEIGHT=40;
var x = getWidth()/2;
var y = getHeight()/2;
    
  var i;

//Direction that the snake moves
var EAST = 0;
var SOUTH = 1;
var WEST = 2;
var NORTH = 3;
var snake;
var rect;
var currentDirection= EAST;
function start(){

 var body = new Rectangle(10,10);
 body.setPosition(x,y);
 body.setColor(Color.GREEN);
 add(body);


setTimer(draw,50);
keyDownMethod(keyDown);
   
}

function elemCheck(x,y)
{
    var elem = getElementAt(x,y);
    
    if(elem != null)
    {
        var lose = new Text("YOU LOSE", "30pt Arial");
        lose.setPosition(100,200);
        add(lose);
    }
}






function draw(i){

if(currentDirection ==EAST){
x = x + 5;
y = y + 0;
}

if(currentDirection ==SOUTH){
x = x + 0;
y = y + 5;
}

if(currentDirection ==WEST){
x = x + -5;
y = y + 0;
}

if(currentDirection ==NORTH){
x = x + 0;
y = y + -5;
}


    elemCheck(x,y);    
  var addBody = new Rectangle(10,10);
    addBody.setPosition(x,y);
    addBody.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    add(addBody);
    

   
}



function keyDown(e){
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
currentDirection=WEST;
}

if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
currentDirection=EAST;
}

if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
currentDirection=NORTH;
}

if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
currentDirection=SOUTH;
}
}
```

I do not have the code to actually stop the snake in yet, I removed it while I am error checking.
But from block one it says "You Lose".

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you done to try debugging your script so far? Breakpoints will do you wonders here :)

Comment: I am doing my programming through Code HS so I cannot put in breakpoints. I can tell that the issue has something to do with x and y always triggering.

Comment: Since you haven't included the body of your `getElementAt()` function, which appears to be supplying the data that your lose checking (`elemCheck()`) relies on, it's really hard to advise or help. I'd first validate that `if(elem != null) {}` is the right way to check for a loss, and then I'd step backwards from there to figure out why `getElementAt(x,y);` is supplying a losing value from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your X and Y is set to the center of the moving square, else it will detect the square you just spawned and end the game.